# How to pass Windows path argument to python subprocess.run()?

Tags: python

I need to run the following command:

```
C:/Jts/tws.exe -J-DjtsConfigDir="C:/Jts"
```

It is running when a call from command line.

How can I run it from python?

I tried:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["C:/Jts/tws.exe", "-J-DjtsConfigDir=\"C:/Jts\""]) # Java exception
subprocess.run(["""C:/Jts/tws.exe -J-DjtsConfigDir=\"C:/Jts\""""]) # FileNotFound exception
```

Nothing worked: I am getting either "FileNotFound" exception or java invalid path exception: "Illegal char <:> at index 2: \C:/Jts/"

Comment: Q: Have you tried Windows backslahes, e.g. `'subprocess.run([C:\\Jts\\tws.exe', '-J -DjtsConfigDir=C:\\Jts\'])`?

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks, it is working. What is my error? Why did I have Java exception?